# How to do these lines within a matrix?

Tags: matrices

i try to do this:

[image: ]](http://www7.pic-upload.de/19.12.13/547iej1463a4.jpg)

How to do that? Can you help me?

Here is my code for the matrix without the lines:

```
\left [
\begin{matrix}
    r_{11} & r_{12} & \dots & r_{1i} & r_{1,i+1} & \dots & r_{1n} & c_1\\
    \lambda_{21} & r_{22} & \dots & r_{2i} & r_{2,i+1} & \dots & r_{2n} & c_2\\
    \lambda_{31} & \lambda_{32} & & r_{3i} & r_{3,i+1} & \dots & r_{3n} & c_3\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \lambda_{i1} & \lambda_{i2} & & r_{ii} & r_{i,i+1} & \dots & r_{in} & c_i\\
    \lambda_{i+1,1} & \lambda_{1+2,2} & & \lambda_{i+1,i} & a_{i+1,i+1}^{(i)} & \dots & a_{i+1,n}^{(i)} & b_{i+1}^{(i)}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
   \lambda_{n,1} & \lambda_{n,2} & \dots & \lambda_{n,i} & a_{n,i+1}^{(i)} & \dots & a_{n,n}^{(i)} & b_n^{(i)}\\
\end{matrix}
\right ]
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you at least provide the code for the matrix without the lines?

Comment: sure i can, i will edit the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `array` it is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left [
%\begin{matrix}
\begin{array}{*7{c}|c}
    r_{11} & r_{12} & \dots & r_{1i} & r_{1,i+1} & \dots & r_{1n} & c_1\\
\cline{1-1}
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \lambda_{21}} & r_{22} & \dots & r_{2i} & r_{2,i+1} & \dots & r_{2n} & c_2\\
\cline{2-2}
    \lambda_{31} &    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\lambda_{32}} & & r_{3i} & r_{3,i+1} & \dots & r_{3n} & c_3\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \lambda_{i1} & \lambda_{i2} & &  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{r_{ii}} & r_{i,i+1} & \dots & r_{in} & c_i\\
\cline{4-8}
    \lambda_{i+1,1} & \lambda_{1+2,2} & & \lambda_{i+1,i} & a_{i+1,i+1}^{(i)} & \dots & a_{i+1,n}^{(i)} & b_{i+1}^{(i)}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \lambda_{n,1} & \lambda_{n,2} & \dots & \lambda_{n,i} & a_{n,i+1}^{(i)} & \dots & a_{n,n}^{(i)} & b_n^{(i)}\\
%\end{matrix}
\end{array}
\right ]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some additional vertical correction would be useful.

*Edit:* It is the logic of probable meaning of the step line, but egreg's suggestion of logic of producing columns is a good alternative.

Comment: I'd use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` in the empty cell, rather than `\multicolumn{1}{|c}{r_{ii}}`; the rules should always go at the end of a column specifier (except for the first column). Adding `\rule{0pt}{3ex}` in the cell after `\cline{4-8}` will make some more room for the high exponents in the row.

Answer (score 1):

With `{bNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar with the classical `{array}` (of the package `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use these nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want in the `\CodeAfter` of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{ccccccc|c}[margin]
    r_{11} & r_{12} & \dots & r_{1i} & r_{1,i+1} & \dots & r_{1n} & c_1\\
    \lambda_{21} & r_{22} & \dots & r_{2i} & r_{2,i+1} & \dots & r_{2n} & c_2\\
    \lambda_{31} & \lambda_{32} & & r_{3i} & r_{3,i+1} & \dots & r_{3n} & c_3\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \lambda_{i1} & \lambda_{i2} & & r_{ii} & r_{i,i+1} & \dots & r_{in} & c_i\\
    \lambda_{i+1,1} & \lambda_{1+2,2} & & \lambda_{i+1,i} & a_{i+1,i+1}^{(i)} & \dots & a_{i+1,n}^{(i)} & b_{i+1}^{(i)}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
   \lambda_{n,1} & \lambda_{n,2} & \dots & \lambda_{n,i} & a_{n,i+1}^{(i)} & \dots & a_{n,n}^{(i)} & b_n^{(i)}\\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|1) -| (3-|2) -| (4-|3) (5-|4) |- (6-|last) ; 
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]